# Can I filter (or create a new) dataset in R based on a number of dependent conditions?

Tags: r

It has been a long time since I have manipulated datasets in R and thus far I have been doing it by hand in excel but that is cumbersome as my dataset isn't small!

I am interested in the following variables:

PATIENT_ID - appears multiple times in dataset

CYCLE_ID - unique

CYCLE_NO - chronological starting at 1 per PATIENT_ID

CALC_ACT - Yes or No

What I need is to create a new dataset which meets the following criteria:
For a single PATIENT_ID I must have one row where CALC_ACT == "Yes" and one row where CALC_ACT == "No".

The CALC_ACT == "Yes" row has to have a higher (but the closest in number) CYCLE_NO than the CALC_ACT == "No" row.

I just need one match per PATIENT_ID and ignore the rest.

For someone where it has been years since doing any programming, the complexity of this is doing my head in!!!

Thankyou so much in advance

In the example below only rows 3 and 4 should be kept. Row 4 (which is CYCLE_NO == 6) is the first time CALC_ACT is Yes and the preceding cycle is No. The rows for PATIENT_ID 222 and 456 do not meet criteria because they need to have both Yes and No for CALC_ACT. Hopefully this makes sense...

```
PatientData <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 222, 222, 222, 456, 456), CYCLE_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10), CYCLE_NO = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), CALC_ACT = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"))

PatientData

   PATIENT_ID CYCLE_ID CYCLE_NO CALC_ACT
1         123        1        1      Yes
2         123        2        3       No
3         123        3        4       No
4         123        4        6      Yes
5         123        5        7      Yes
6         222        6        2       No
7         222        7        3       No
8         222        8        4       No
9         456        9        1      Yes
10        456       10        2      Yes
```

Comment: Welcome to SO Soph! Could you provide some example data for people to use, as well as an example of what you'd like the data to look like in the end? You could use the actual data by using `dput(your_dataframe)` and pasting the output, or make one up. This will help ensure people are giving you an answer which definitely works for your problem.

Comment: Is this supposed to be a random selection? Or can we just pick the first row per patient where `CALC_ACT = "No"` row, and then the first `CALC_ACT = "Yes"` row after it? What do we do if there is not `Yes` row following the `No` row - do you still want the `Yes` row?

Comment: Thanks I've added a sample data set.

Comment: In the example above only rows 3 and 4 should be kept. Row 4 (which is CYCLE_NO == 6) is the first time CALC_ACT is Yes and the preceding cycle is No. The rows for PATIENT_ID 222 and 456 do not meet criteria because they need to have both Yes and No for CALC_ACT. Hopefully this makes sense...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a function which should work as per the logic.

```
return_rows <- function(CALC_ACT, CYCLE_NO) {
  #indices of 'yes' rows
  yes_ind <- which(CALC_ACT == 'Yes') 
  #indices of 'no' rows
  no_ind <- which(CALC_ACT == 'No')
  #Only if both the yes and no rows are present else don't select any row
  if(length(yes_ind) && length(no_ind)) {
    #Get the minimum length of yes and no rows
    n <- min(length(yes_ind), length(no_ind))
    #Get the first value where yes no has higher CYCLE_NO than the no row
    ind <- which(CYCLE_NO[yes_ind[1:n]] > CYCLE_NO[no_ind[1:n]])[1]
    #Return the corresponding index
    sort(c(yes_ind[ind], no_ind[ind]))
  } else 0
}
```

Apply this function for each `PATIENT_ID` -

```
PatientData %>%
  arrange(PATIENT_ID, CYCLE_NO) %>%
  group_by(PATIENT_ID) %>%
  slice(return_rows(CALC_ACT, CYCLE_NO)) %>%
  ungroup

#  PATIENT_ID CYCLE_ID CYCLE_NO CALC_ACT
#       <dbl>    <dbl>    <dbl> <chr>   
#1        123        3        4 No      
#2        123        4        6 Yes
```

Answer (score 0):

This code should work

```
library(data.table)

PatientData <- data.frame(PATIENT_ID = c(123, 123, 123, 123, 123, 222, 222, 222, 456, 456), CYCLE_ID = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10),
                          CYCLE_NO = c(1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2), CALC_ACT = c("Yes", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes", "No", "No", "No", "Yes", "Yes"))

d1 = data.table(PatientData[order(PatientData$PATIENT_ID, PatientData$CYCLE_NO),])

d1$CALC_ACT1 = ifelse(d1$CALC_ACT == 'Yes',1,0)

d1[ , diff := CALC_ACT1 - shift(CALC_ACT1), by = PATIENT_ID]   

out = d1[c(which(d1$diff == 1), (which(d1$diff == 1) -1)),]

out
```